# Deleting a comment which then makes nonsense of a response

Tags: discussion

I commented, admittedly somewhat tongue in cheek, on @guest271314 's answer to [this](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/14112/when-did-the-ancient-egyptians-discover-or-reach-the-nile-headwaters)  question - essentially I was saying that we all come from somewhere, but that doesn't mean we are familiar with our (distant) origins. **My** comment has been deleted, but **not** the OP's reply, which now makes very little sense! Can someone explain how a riposte can be allowed to stand alone? It makes no sense to me at least.

Comment: This was my bad, I anticipated guest would continue to comment, but still forgot to refresh the page afterwards.

Comment: No problem. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at the timeline, the OP replied to your comment after the other comments had been deleted.

You're right, of course, that it makes no sense for that riposte to stand alone, so I have deleted it.

Comment: Thank you very much ! :-)